# Java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when adding omnifaces 1.4.1 to liferay project

Tags: jsf, primefaces, glassfish, liferay, omnifaces

I am using **JSF 2.0 with Liferay and Glassfish and primefaces 3.5**.

I've read about **omnifaces** and its interesting.

I've added `omnifaces 1.4.1 jar file` to my Liferay project in `web-inf\lib`.

An **exception** is thrown after page is rendered:

> java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at
>   org.omnifaces.context.Omn.PartialViewContext$OmniPartialResponseWriter.startDocumnet(OmniPartial
>   View Context.java)

Is there any configurations I must add or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

From the 3rd paragraph of the [OmniFaces homepage](http://omnifaces.org):

> ... Note that OmniFaces is **not** designed for portlets.

Liferay is a portlet environment. OmniFaces is designed for servlet environments. The `ExceptionInInitializerError` which you're facing is most likely caused by a missing `javax.servlet` dependency which should have been manifested as `NoClassDefFoundError` further down in the stack trace.